# Crash, when getting the number of images stored in the SD

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I'm trying to get the number of all images stored in the SD, but I don't know why the App crashes.

Code:

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/images");
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
//int numberOfImages=files.length;

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "fdds"+files.length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

LogCat:

> 03-19 11:54:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(11775): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-19 11:54:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(11775): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidbook.MediaStoreDemo/com.androidbook.MediaStoreDemo.MediaStoreDemoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   03-19 11:54:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(11775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
>   03-19 11:54:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(11775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>   03-19 11:54:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(11775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>   03-19 11:54:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(11775):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
>   03-19 11:54:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(11775):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   03-19 11:54:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(11775):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   03-19 11:54:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(11775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
>   03-19 11:54:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(11775):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-19 11:54:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(11775):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   03-19 11:54:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(11775):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
>   03-19 11:54:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(11775):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
>   03-19 11:54:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(11775):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   03-19 11:54:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(11775): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   03-19 11:54:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(11775):    at com.androidbook.MediaStoreDemo.MediaStoreDemoActivity.onCreate(MediaStoreDemoActivity.java:31)
>   03-19 11:54:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(11775):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   03-19 11:54:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(11775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)

Comment: You simply facing a issue with null, its a basic error that anyone can easily identify. You should learn some basic programming. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
if(files != null)
{
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "fdds"+files.length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**public File[] listFiles ()**

**Returns** an array of files contained in the directory represented by this file. **The result is null if this file is not a directory.** The paths of the files in the array are absolute if the path of this file is absolute, they are relative otherwise.

So just check `/images` directory..

Comment: now the App, does not crash, but the Toast display nothing, and there are pictures in the SD???!!

Comment: can u tel me how to know the file in which the pictures are saved in SD??

Comment: and inside the Camera directory there are pictures and other directories, i changed the path to /Camera.....but still displays nothing

Comment: So null values is obvious result.. Just write new question about how to get stored images from sdcard in SO.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code:

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "images");
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
//int numberOfImages=files.length;

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "fdds"+files.length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Now your app should not throw any exception.

You should use `image` instead of `/image`